# How can VPN port forwarding be an alternative to port forwarding on the router?

Tags: routing, vpn, nat

According to this [article](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm), if you cannot forward ports on your router (no access to router admin panel for example), you can sign up for a VPN service and setup a port forward on the VPN to get around the router admin panel limitation.

How is that possible though? Wouldn't you need to port forward on both the VPN and the router since there's now two layers of NAT? One layer of NAT from the router and the second layer of NAT from the VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tunnel just encapsulates your packets inside an outer packet. You don't NAT within the tunnel. If the tunnel endpoint is on the inside the NAT, you NAT the outer packets of the tunnel, and forward the tunnel port if the tunnel is originated from outside. If the tunnel endpoint is in the router, this isn't necessary.

The tunnel creates a network link, just as if you ran a cable between the endpoints.